# JAXB @XmlJavaTypeAdapter usage

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I had been struggling to have `@XMLJavaTypeAdapter` to make it working as per my need. I could be wrong with my understanding. Please help me to understand in better way.

Requirement:
For example:
I have a transport XML with list of mappings objects as below:

```
<transport>
    <mappings>
        <product>XXX</product>
        <eventName>XXX</eventName>
        <destination>XXX</destination>
        <destinationType>XXX</destinationType>
    </mappings>
</transport>
```

Using JAXB, I am able to read XML as a `List<Mappings>` objects.

I would like to have my in-memory representation of `List<Mappings>` as a `Map<String,Mappings>`, where key in map is product:eventName and Use in my code Map instead of `List<Mapping>`.

I am bit confused with usage of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` and not able to figure out How can i achieve this.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 7):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could leverage the `@XmlPath` extension in MOXy to do the following:

**Transport**

The `Transport` class makes use of the `@XmlPath` extension.  Without `@XmlPath`a grouping element called `mappings` will be added to the document.

```
package forum8403623;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transport {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MappingsAdapter.class)
    @XmlPath(".")
    private Map<String, Mapping> mappings = new HashMap<String, Mapping>();

}
```

**Mapping**

```
package forum8403623;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"product", "eventName", "destination", "destinationType"})
public class Mapping {

    String product;
    String eventName;
    String destination;
    String destinationType;

}
```

**MappingsAdapter**

The following class is responsible for converting to/from the `Map<String, Mapping>` to the representation we will be using for the XML mapping.

```
package forum8403623;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MappingsAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MappingsAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<String, Mapping>>{

    @Override
    public Map<String, Mapping> unmarshal(AdaptedMap v) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Mapping> mappings = new HashMap<String, Mapping>();
        for(Mapping mapping : v.mappings) {
            mappings.put(mapping.product, mapping);
        }
        return mappings;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, Mapping> v) throws Exception {
        AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
        for(Entry<String,Mapping> entry : v.entrySet()) {
            adaptedMap.mappings.add(entry.getValue());
        }
        return adaptedMap;
    }

    static class AdaptedMap {
        public List<Mapping> mappings = new ArrayList<Mapping>();
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum8403623;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transport.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum8403623/input.xml");
        Transport transport = (Transport) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(transport, System.out);
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called jaxb.properties in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for your quick response with excellent example. I really appreciate that.

I followed the same steps as mentioned above and by adding few System.out statements, I do see that Adapter's marshall/unmarshall methods are being called. BUT unfortunately, output is always empty XML.

It looks like MappingsAdapter.AdaptedMap List is not getting filled up during Unmarhshalling Transport object using XML.

Is there anything i am doing wrong ? Please advise.

Once again, Thank you so much for your help and patience.

Raj

Comment: @Raj - To use the example exactly as I have it you will need to have eclipselink.jar on your classpath.  You can obtain it from:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/.  If you are using the JAXB reference implementation you may find the following article useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: +1 for the first blog link "XmlAdapter - JAXB's Secret Weapon"